# Using SetJoin in JPA2

Tags: jpa-2.0

how can i code the sql below using JPA2 CriteriaBuilder?

```
select p from parent p, child c where c.parent_id=p.id and c.code='222' and c.type='SD';
```

i tried to use SetJoin but couldn't figure how to use.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One alternative matching your query:

```
public void foo() {
    // select p from parent p, child c where c.parent_id=p.id and c.code='222' and c.type='SD';
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery <Parent> query = cb.createQuery(Parent.class);

    Root <Parent> r1 = query.from(Parent.class);
    Root <Child> r2 = query.from(Child.class);

    Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[] {
        cb.equal(r1.get(Parent_.id), r2.get(Child_.parentId)),
        cb.equal(r2.get(Child_.code), "222"),
        cb.equal(r2.get(Child_.type, "SD"))
    };

    query.select(r1);
    query.where(predicates);

    List <Parent> result = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

There are numerous ways to do what you want but as I don't know anything about your model it's hard to give a proper example other than the one above.

Provided that the Parent and Child are associated you could also do something like:

```
public void foo() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery <Parent> query = cb.createQuery(Parent.class);

    Root <Child> child = query.from(Child.class);
    Join <Child, Parent> parent = child.join(Child_.parent);

    Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[] {
        cb.equal(child.get(Child_.code), "222"),
        cb.equal(child.get(Child_.type, "SD"))
    };

    query.select(parent);
    query.where(predicates);

    List <Parent> result = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

But that's based on a lot of assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Magnus for detailed information, i ve solved my problem like below:

```
predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate, criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join("children", JoinType.INNER).get("code"), location.getCode()));
```